# What is the diffrence between @interface <File Name> : NSObject and @interface NSObject (Filename)?

Tags: objective-c

File name : ABC.h & ABC.m

1)

```
@interface < ABC > : NSObject

//methods

@end
```

2)

```
@interface NSObject (ABC)

//methods

@end
```

In first , methods are not called in another file.
In second , methods are called in another file.

What is difference between first & second code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

```
@interface  ABC  : NSObject

//methods

@end
```

Subclassing - For accessing the instance we instantiate the **ABC**

2)

```
@interface NSObject (ABC)

//methods

@end
```

Category - For accessing we don't instance of **ABC**. instead you may **access the method using the instance of NSObject.** It is like adding additional method to NSObject class itself.

Answer (score 2):

For First one :

1) @interface < ABC > : NSObject

---> This syntax is for class declaration.

---> If you want to call class than you have to create object of that class

For Second one :

2) @interface NSObject (ABC)

---> This syntax is for category declaration.

---> Category is the extension of particular predefined class.

---> Below is the example how can use category of NSString

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSString(MyAdditions)

+(NSString *)getCopyRightString;

@end

@implementation NSString(MyAdditions)

+(NSString *)getCopyRightString{
    return @"Copyright TutorialsPoint.com 2013";
}

@end


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

   NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
   NSString *copyrightString = [NSString getCopyRightString];
   NSLog(@"Accessing Category: %@",copyrightString);
   [pool drain];
    return 0;
}
```

Now when we compile and run the program, we will get the following result.

```
2013-09-22 21:19:12.125 Categories[340:303] Accessing Category: Copyright TutorialsPoint.com 2013
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface < ABC > : NSObject
```

Above creates a class(inheriting from `NSObject`) written inside <>. To use the method of this class you need to create instance of this class.

```
@interface NSObject (ABC)
```

This one is a category on `NSObject`. And all category methods are available for all descendents of the class on which you make. Hence in this case it is in `NSObject` and most of the classes inherits from `NSObject`, (few are from `NSProxy`).

Comment: Note that you must import the category anywhere you intend to use it.

Comment: You'd be surprised how many beginners make that mistake! It's easy to forget when your category is on something like NSObject, after all you don't need to import NSObject.h!

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface < ABC > : NSObject
//methods
@end
```

This is to create the header file for the class ABC where you can declare all you public variables and methods.

```
@interface NSObject (ABC)
//methods
@end
```

This is the Category declaration on `NSObject` for the class ABC

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface < ABC > : NSObject

//methods and ivars to your new class

@end
```

You area going to create a new class here that must be your need to have it in some part of application. But there are cases when you have a class developed already but not the exact thing you are looking for. For that, you create a category. The 2nd option where you just add your desired functionality to make it perfect.

```
@interface NSObject (ABC)

//methods to category of a specific class like NSString etc

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

1) @interface < ABC > : NSObject

//methods

@end

is a class declaration.

2) @interface NSObject (ABC)

//methods

@end

is a category.